# Clone Google Source Repository without gcloud

Tags: git, gcloud, google-cloud-source-repos

I am currently cloning the git repository present in Google Cloud Source repository using

```
gcloud source repos clone sample_repo --project=sample_project
```

Can I clone git repository present in Google Cloud Source Repository without using gcloud?
Like,

```
git clone https://source.developers.google.com/p/sample_project/r/sample_repo
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gcloud does not do much when cloning, it only sets up credentials. In fact if you run

`$ gcloud source repos clone default --dry-run`

command (with `--dry-run` flag) you will see the `git` command `gcloud` runs under the hood:

`git clone https://source.developers.google.com/p/YOUR_PROJECT/r/default \
  --config credential.helper='!gcloud auth git-helper --account=YOUR_ACCOUNT --ignore-unknown $@'`

gcloud credential helper essentially just provides access token for the account. So if you have a way to get credentials you can wire in them into git this way.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, with one small change. Instead of:

`--config credential.helper=`, y used:

`--config credential.https://source.developers.google.com/.helper=`