# Is there a way to pass access tokens when calling git clone over HTTPS for Google Source Repository

Tags: git, google-cloud-functions, gitpython, google-cloud-source-repos, google-source-repositories

I have been trying to use Google Cloud Functions (python 3.7) to basically clone a Google Source Repository. I'm using [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library and the service account for that Cloud Functions has **Source Repository Reader** access on the repository that I want to clone.

Initially, I tried passing [gcloud.sh credential.helper](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes#linux-or-macos) to git config, but it seems that Cloud SDK is not installed on Cloud Functions environment (at least in Python 3.7 environment). Here is a gist of my code:

```
from git import Repo
import tempfile

def git_clone():
    
    local_repo = tempfile.gettempdir()+'/localrepo'
    repo = Repo.init(local_repo)
    origin = repo.create_remote('origin', 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/PROJECT/r/REPO')

    repo.config_writer().set_value("user", "name", "gsr-to-gcs-backup-function").release()
    repo.config_writer().set_value("user", "email", "gsr-to-gcs-backup-function@PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com").release()
    repo.config_writer().set_value("credential \"https://source.developers.google.com\"", "helper", "gcloud.sh").release()

    assert origin.exists()
    assert origin == repo.remotes.origin == repo.remotes['origin']
    
    origin.fetch()
```

The function will throw the below error if run on Cloud Functions since by default if there is no credential helper, the **https** method will ask for **Username** and **Password**.

> git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
> cmdline: git fetch -v origin stderr: 'fatal: could not read Username
> for 'https://source.developers.google.com': Input/output error'

I could only find the below answer to pass token along with the **git clone** command but it doesn't answer how to pass the token:

[Clone Google Source Repository without gcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50129412/clone-google-source-repository-without-gcloud)

If I initiate that command from cloud shell, it will be just hung:

```
gcloud auth git-helper store --account=YOUR_ACCOUNT --ignore-unknown $@
```

Here's something similar that I plan to achieve using the above (not a correct code):

```
Repo.clone_from("https://source.developers.google.com/p/PROJECT/r/REPO",tempfile.gettempdir(), multi_options=['--config credential.helper={}'.format(MYTOKEN)], branch='master')
```

I don't want to put an SSH key instead as a method to clone as I want to deploy it to production later on and rotating keys would be cumbersome.

Comment: I personally strongly prefer ssh keys for git because the auth process is straight forward and if done right far more secure than a shared secret.  is rotating ssh keys really any more cumbersome than rotating passwords?  Obviously, that choice is up to you.

Comment: Can we create SSH keys for service accounts? I think the one that we add from our account would have my privilege. That would be too much of a security risk. If I understood differently and if there is a way to add keys for service accounts, I may use SSH keys nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Username that is asked is nothing but the service account address and credentials can be a temporarily generated OAuth 2.0 access token. So, what I ended up doing was:

```
from git import Repo
import tempfile
import urllib.parse
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests

def get_token():
    creds, project = google.auth.default()
    # creds.valid is False, and creds.token is None
    # # Need to refresh credentials to populate those
    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    creds.refresh(auth_req)
    # Now you can use creds.token
    return creds.token

def url_parse():
    query = 'gsr-to-gcs-backup-function@PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    return urllib.parse.quote(query)

def git_clone():
    encoded_url = url_parse()
    credentials = get_token()
    
    local_repo = tempfile.gettempdir()+'/localrepo' 
    Repo.clone_from(f"https://{encoded_url}:{credentials}@source.developers.google.com/p/PROJECT/r/REPO",local_repo, branch='master')

def main(*args):
    git_clone()
```

**NOTE: This is only a part of my code. What I want is to copy this to a GCS bucket. But that is out of purview of this question.**